# Variable does not exist:OwnerId while saving Apex Trigger Handler Class

Tags: apex, developer-console

I have added a new single line code, and i am receiving the below errors attached in image, Kindly help me in resolving the same.

[image]

Comment: Just remove everything after "." and ownerId - mailElement.setTargetObjectId(meetingMemberElement.OCE__Meeting__c);

Comment: @Rohit Ok, but may i please know what change needs to be made here if i want to add "OwnerId"

Comment: Do you want to set targetObject Id as the meetingMemberElement ownerId ? It's not clear from the question.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra parenthesis in your code. The line 138 should be this instead:

```
mailElement.setTargetObjectId(meetingMemberElement.OCE__Meeting__r.OwnerId);
```

What this does is, it sets the Owner Id of the Meeting record as the Target Object Id of the `SingleEmailMessage`.

Comment: Close, but `OCE__Meeting__c` should be `OCE__Meeting__r`, since it's presumably a relationship field.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thankyou so much for the answer

Comment: @sfdcfox I feel so stupid ‍♂️ You are indeed correct, editing my answer.